# Docker - cannot connect to the Docker daemon

Tags: docker

I'm trying to start a new Docker container with:

```
docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

However I get the following

[image]

Checking for the daemon, I get

[image]

Any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same kind of problem couple of days ago on **LINUX**, try below command,use on `sudo` mode

```
sudo usermod -aG docker your_user_name
```

**OR**

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)
```

then logout and log in.:) walla

For Mac : see https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978931/dayel-ostraco

Comment: And Windows? Anybody has a solution for W10 Home? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem.  In my case, ps showed that the docker daemon was not running.  Problem was, I had no clue why.

$ sudo docker -d

attempts to start the daemon manually and displays an error message if it fails.

In my case, my kernel was a bit old and didn't support docker.

There are lots of reason why the daemon may not start, so it's best to find out if it's running and if not, why not.